# Get all work hours from Jira

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I would like to get all work hours from JIRA. I tried this code for the beginning:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.JiraRestClient;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.NullProgressMonitor;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.domain.BasicProject;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.jersey.JerseyJiraRestClientFactory;
import java.net.URI;

public class JiraImpl
{
    private static final String JIRA_URL = "https://jira.atlassian.com";
    private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME = "test";
    private static final String JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "test";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        JiraRestClient jira;
        JerseyJiraRestClientFactory clientFactory = new JerseyJiraRestClientFactory();
        jira = clientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(new URI(JIRA_URL),
            JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("Connection established to >> " + JIRA_URL);

        Iterable<BasicProject> allProjects = jira.getProjectClient().getAllProjects(new NullProgressMonitor());
    }
}
```

But I get: `Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: Client response status: 401`

What is the proper way to get all projects?

Comment: 401 means "unauthorized", so there's something wrong with either the credentials that you use (can you login manually with that user?), or with the "test" user's permissions (can your user see any projects?), or with the way you create your client.

Comment: Also: the title of your question doesn't seem related to the question itself?

Answer (score 0):

To get all projects You can use this `ComponentAccessor.getProjectManager().getProjectObjects();` This will return all projects ordered by name.
Link to docs [ProjectManager](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/project/ProjectManager.html#getProjectObjects())

REST API GET `/rest/api/2/project`

```
baseUrl + /rest/api/2/project
```

> Returns all projects which are visible for the currently logged in
>   user. If no user is logged in, it returns the list of projects that
>   are visible when using anonymous access.

Api docs [LINK](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/project-getAllProjects)

Comment: Thanks, but how I can all this object from JiraRestClient jira? Can you extend the code example please?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question. It refers to the JIRA java api instead of the JIRA REST API and it will only work if you're developing an add-on for a standalone JIRA (not cloud), or use the Script Runner add-on for a standalone JIRA.

Comment: Check REST command from answer, it should work. Ask if You need more help.